# Conway's surreal numbers and the Collatz iteration as a game?

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems, combinatorial-game-theory, collatz-conjecture, surreal-numbers

Let us define a game based on the Collatz function $C(n) = n/2$ if $n$ is even, otherwise $=3n+1$.

Each number $n$ represents a game played by left $L$ and right $R$:

$$n = \{L_n | R_n \}$$

The rules of the game are:

If $n$ is even, the left player can play the game:

$$n = \{n/2 | \emptyset \}$$

If $n \neq 1$ is odd, the right player can play the game:

$$n = \{\emptyset| 3n+1 \}$$

If $n=1$, the game is over as no player can make a move:

$$n = \{\emptyset| \emptyset \}$$

Assuming the Collatz conjecture, this game starting with an arbitrary number $n$, has always an end.

So these games define surreal numbers and we could add and multiply, negate those games, which I think would be fun.

**Q: How do I find the numeric value of these surreal numbers? Is there an algorithm to do this?**

Example:

```
x7  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x22}))
x22  =  (frozenset({x11}), frozenset())
x11  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x34}))
x34  =  (frozenset({x17}), frozenset())
x17  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x52}))
x52  =  (frozenset({x26}), frozenset())
x26  =  (frozenset({x13}), frozenset())
x13  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x40}))
x40  =  (frozenset({x20}), frozenset())
x20  =  (frozenset({x10}), frozenset())
x10  =  (frozenset({x5}), frozenset())
x5  =  (frozenset(), frozenset({x16}))
x16  =  (frozenset({x8}), frozenset())
x8  =  (frozenset({x4}), frozenset())
x4  =  (frozenset({x2}), frozenset())
x2  =  (frozenset({x1}), frozenset())
x1  =  (frozenset(), frozenset())
```

sorted by value:

```
[1, 5, 13, 17, 11, 7, 9, 2, 10, 26, 34, 22, 14, 4, 20, 52, 28, 8, 40, 16]
```

[Example Sage-Math-Script.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJydVctq3DAU3fsr1IGCnLhJZrIIDXhVuiiYLKZdBIwJzkjTiJFlI3kmskv_vVeSX_I8AvVKurrn3HMfkgndok3JeV63WISPAYKPbZH4vIrjO7c1n6T1XgokblfWRLmiR4f3V-J6aY0BAVbOVP1txsw5ilGa2fX7G-MUiU_xcmTi_CavKioIIAajAMwoMZj72YATGRDDWKwGtZeS5vykDF9fTyvpgUpFsTMoBY5__tr1tpSIISaQzMVvijkVmPMwHMUXhpSnLBssUMginubnONNlBq54K8uWCkVrnGZh5O3G5Ck3JLNudDTFnMbYblfZJbZp387R-HjwuL8qrpdZT9TVWSlXY7EvXqFk8xoTAqyEbSzf2YafGDXzPQP2kEu80ItrVUsgDb3zp5liz_d2FYbnS9BPVD_KQ1mGOfpfEX7MKdLeDCPqWMZ4aVzR0mfTjafgjACn8HLkPoxP1nWNENc1ppLyncpfb7nAOmq6pukk0muAaLtrkqgxu8bNP5PmwgjCalYa6TnnOBVl7XE1keahvSuam8uik677im4A-zFeRtrhG2nwzTrzpm6mIhdkzuzy25RFlUs6yY0dJ23hM_Xh0bt2dxF-ogDHFF-W55_N7sm0qnNCfvqSdRx7rT2CN71n85Gn_rDFbQLLCYmTw02qJzpqvdvkZi-g6tNxHNLoJqGxuCZB_WS261Nx5BDHdl73nbfe7fpCHOlPzBjH3JM2idq1N0NtANUm9-Zw9oP4CkA4-SEO_ePVsgqD5eaQ8z1VOIzMZkcbWIKvibozQcHq6l1JJmq8Q9ECGBbGO91BHgHILtB2LzZ1WXKFWFGVskabonqpyxfgCwJYmx_dYMHdCAPYkS4UQChBrw2yah4XYXeSOs3pIbN1OBhFztnXDqwxBAizkfO7zouKWy4hTElmz_nDJElw8JKMkEvSHJgs_wE3zVsq&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Comment: also asked at MO, since I am not sure about the difficulty of the question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375541/surreal-numbers-and-the-collatz-iteration-as-a-game

Comment: Conway's games don't suit Collatz's conjecture well in that "Collatz's game" is naturally presented as a one player game with only one option at each turn. Also, it is unclear to me whether you are setting $n=\{\frac{n}{2}\ | \ \varnothing\}$ as a definition or if you are saying there is an equality. If $n$ is a natural number seen as a game, then $\{\frac{n}{2}\ | \ \varnothing\}$ is a well-defined game which is also a natural number, and we have $n=\{\frac{n}{2}\ | \ \varnothing\}$ if and only if $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Comment: @nombre: the example with $n=7$ should make clear what I mean.

Comment: If $n=7$, then the game $\{\varnothing \ | \ 3 n +1\}$ has value $0$ (this yields the same value for all natural numbers $n$). The thing is, there is no nice relation between $C(n)$ and $\{\varnothing \ | \ 3 n +1\}$.

Comment: @nombre: We have $v(1)=0$,$v(2)=1$,$v(4)=3$. I do not understand your claim, that every number has value 0.

Comment: @nombre: I meant $v(4)=2$ where $v(n)$ denotes the numeric value of the game $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Notation Issue

In Combinatorial Game Theory, integers like $4$ each denote a particular game or game value, like $\{3\mid\,\}$ (note that we don't write $\varnothing$ in this notation).

As nombre pointed out in the comments, the written equations like "$n=\{\frac{n}{2}\mid\varnothing\}$" are rarely/never true under standard notation for combinatorial games.

If you don't intend to be referencing the standard meanings of $n$, $3n+1$, and $\frac{n}{2}$ in this notation, you should either have a gigantic disclaimer that the usual notation does not apply, or just use something else for the games you would like to describe.

I'll use $g(n)$ where you have $n$, etc. So we have $g(1)=\{\,\mid\,\}$, $g(n)=\{g(n/2)\mid\,\}$ for even $n$, and $g(n)=\{\,\mid g(3n+1)\}$ for odd $n>1$. Technically, this is only a valid definition for all $n$ if the Collatz conjecture is true.

## Example Numeric Values

Let's start building a table and see if we see any patterns. $g(1)=\{\,\mid\,\}=0$. $g(2)=\{g(1)\mid\,\}=\{0\mid\,\}=1$. $$\begin{align}g(3)&=\{\,\mid g(10)\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{g(5)\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid g(16)\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{g(8)\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{g(4)\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\{g(2)\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\{1\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{2\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{3\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid 4\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{0\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid 1\}\\&=0\end{align}$$ $g(4)=2$, $g(5)=0$, $g(6)=\{g(3)\mid\,\}=\{0\mid\,\}=1$.
$$\begin{align}g(7)&=\{\,\mid g(22)\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{g(11)\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid g(34)\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{g(17)\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid g(52)\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{g(26)\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{g(13)\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\{\,\mid g(40)\}\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\{\,\mid \{g(20)\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\{\,\mid \{\{g(10)\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\{\,\mid \{\{1\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\{\,\mid \{2\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\{\,\mid 3\}\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{0\mid\,\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{1\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid 2\}\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid \{0\mid\,\}\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{\{\,\mid 1\}\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid \{0\mid\,\}\}\\&=\{\,\mid 1\}\\&=0\end{align}$$

### Claim

In general, the numeric value of $g(n)$ appears to be the highest exponent $m$ such that $2^m$ divides $n$.

## Proof

Let's assume, for induction, that the claim is true of all the values of $g$ that arise during the calculation of $g(n)$. Note that $g(1)=0$. If $n$ is even, then $g(n)=\{g(n/2)\mid\,\}=g(n/2)+1$, which matches the highest power of $2$ for $n$. If $n$ is odd and greater than $1$, then $g(n)=\{\,\mid g(3n+1)\}$. Since $3n+1$ is even, $g(3n+1)\ge1$, so that $g(n)=0$, as desired.

Comment: Thank your for your detailed answer.

Comment: So the OP's question gives a nice piecewise recursive definition of the $2$-adic valuation!

Comment: @nombre Yes, but $n+1$ in place of $3n+1$ would have done the same.

Comment: What changes if we replace $3n+1$ with $(3n+1)/2$ when $n$ is odd?

Comment: @stackExchangeUser Then the values of $g(n)$ for odd $n$ are $1-$"number of steps of $(3n+1)/2$ it takes to get to an even number from $n$". For example, we'd have $g(3)=1-2=-1$ since $3\to5\to8$ takes $2$ steps. The values for even $n$ are unchanged.

Comment: @MarkS. : I do not think that for even numbers your observation holds: For instance $g(14)=0$, see https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=ppddjg for more examples.

Comment: @MarkS. Suppose $m,n$ iterate to $1$ with the Collatz function. Then $g(m) = v_2(m)$ and $g(n) = v_2(n)$. Adding those two games, we find $g(m)+g(n) = v_2(m)+v_2(n)=v_2(mn)$, which is also a game. Can we prove that $g(mn) = v_2(mn)$, without assuming first, that $mn$ iterate to $1$ with the Collatz function? If yes, this would reduce the Collatz problem to prime numbers.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser no, that cannot be done because $g(mn)$ is only *defined* if $mn$ iterates to 1. If Collatz were false, then we have problems with $g$: like an extra loop in the Collatz graph means that $g(x)$ is defined in terms of $g(x)$ and in fact goes on forever (is a loopy game).

Comment: @MarkS. Ok, I understand.

Comment: If the downvoter would like to give criticism either privately (see my profile) or publicly, I would welcome it so the answer (or my answering habits) can be improved.